# CRAN check: warning vignette engine knitr::rmarkdown is not available

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, r-package

I'm trying for the first time to add some vignettes in my package. Everything is ok on my computer. No warning, no error. Then I uploaded it to the CRAN windows builder

```
devtools::check_win_release()
```

And I got this warning relative to vignettes:

```
* checking re-building of vignette outputs ... [7s] WARNING
Error in re-building vignettes:
  ...
Warning in engine$weave(file, quiet = quiet, encoding = enc) :
  The vignette engine knitr::rmarkdown is not available, because the rmarkdown package is not installed. Please install it.
Failed with error:  'there is no package called 'rmarkdown''
Quitting from lines 172-178 (las.Rmd) 
Error: processing vignette 'las.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
cannot open the connection
Execution halted
```

I don't think that this issue is related to the content of the package. Can I assume that it is an "ok" warning? Can I fix it?

My `DESCRIPTION` file contains:

```
Suggests: knitr
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

- My `vignettes/` folder contains one `Rmd` file
- My `inst/doc/` folder contains the `Rmd` `R` and `html` auto generated files relative the the original `Rmd` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `rmarkdown` in your Suggests.

Comment: Ho ok, I missed that one. I send again the package to the CRAN builder to check if everything is goes well.